# my screen freeze wehen i start a snake program

Tags: python-3.x

^ i just startet using python and tryd to code snake as a game i have this code since now

```
import turtle
import os

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.title("Space Invaders")

border_pen = turtle.Turtle()
border_pen.speed(0)
border_pen.color("white")
border_pen.penup()
border_pen.setposition(-300,-300)
border_pen.pendown()
border_pen.pensize(3)
for side in range(4):
    border_pen.fd(600)
    border_pen.lt(90)
border_pen.hideturtle()

player = turtle.Turtle()
player.color("blue")
player.shape("triangle")
player.penup()
player.speed(0)
player.setposition(0, -250)
player.setheading(90)

playerspeed = 15

def move_left():
    x = player.xcor()
    x -= playerspeed
    if x < -280:
        x = - 280
    player.setx(x)

def move_right():
    x = player.xcor()
    x += playerspeed
    if x > 280:
        x = 280

    player.setx(x)

turtle.listen()
turtle.onkey(move_left(), "Left")
turtle.onkey(move_right, "Right")


delay = input("Press enter to finish.")
```

everything is working on the code but the problem is i cant look at the game cause it crashes all the time it says "no respond" and then i need to close it can u help me
i have a 64bit laptop
but i need to use 32bit to open it and that why i tryd i installed 32bit and still not working help me please

Comment: Hi! Your code works fine for me in my local environment. It shows a blue triangle that I can move left and right (although there is a bug in your code for move_left). How are you running the code and do you get any error messages?

Comment: It freezes on my machine too after the blue triangle is displayed. (Windows 10). What OS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You really really got me here. I could not find a single error and yet it freezes, but not for everyone. Ok, I *did* find one error:

Change `turtle.onkey(move_left(), "Left")` to `turtle.onkey(move_left, "Left")` first.

The problem, I discovered, is your very last line:

```
delay = input("Press enter to finish.")
```

I'm not quite sure, but I suspect that the input() statement is waiting for input causing the rest of the program to freeze until Enter is pressed. But that also closes the program. Obviously not the right choice to keep the window alive. Replace this line with:

```
wn.mainloop()
```

And now your program shouldn't freeze any more, but let's you move the blue triangle.